# Is it possible to use javac just to check correctness and not produce any output?

Tags: java, parsing, javac

Can I run javac (or another tool, if javac can't be used as such) just to check for correctness of a project:  if there are syntax errors or missing imports, incorrect use of annotations, access violations, *en somme*, anything that would be reported by eclipse when you choose the action build.

Answer (score 3):

You can run javac with two options :

1. -c to give the path of you files,
2. -s for path to libraries

If you really want to check the project at it is, I would recommand to use a dependency manager like Maven or Ant which can check errors, compile, packages, etc..., but it will need some configuration in your project using a configuration file (a pom.xml for Maven)

Comment: Will check Maven out.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding an introduction to maven. I use gradle myself (but have a extremely basic understanding of it). I don't really understand that kind of stuff, since I come from a C# background and the Solution is all you need to deploy.

Comment: Maven is just an "extra" program you'll need to install and configure (PATH environment). Then, you have to add a file, "pom.xml" in the root of your project, describing it.
Take a look at : https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Then take a look about the "maven shaded plugin", it's some lines to add to your maven file to configure the "package" command to embbed your dependencies with your jar ;)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that javac runs properly does not prevent you from getting [NoClassDefFoundError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) problems due to missing dependencies.

Comment: This does not answer the question and would be better suited as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of an Eclipse build just without producing class files is [invoking](http://help.eclipse.org/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_batch_compiler.htm) the [JDT batch compiler](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.5.2-201602121500/#JDTCORE) with option `-d none` (see [here](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) for available versions).